# Find Record if value does not exist?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am having problem with the SQL Query.

I want to find `StatusID = 1` in the `records` table IF `StatusID = 2` does not exist.

I have tried the query:

```
SELECT * FROM records AS A
   LEFT JOIN records AS B on B.StoreID = A.StoreID
WHERE A.StatusID = 1 AND B.StatusID != 2
```

It is still showing the result even if `StatusID = 2` is exist.

Note: `StoreID` are the ref id in the records table.

Comment: I do not get it. Could you rephrase it?

Comment: @MarianP Find `StatusID = 1` in the `records` table IF `StatusID = 2` does not exist in the table

Comment: But if StatusID = 2 do you want no results, or the results with 2?

Comment: @MarianP Not in the records table. You can have multiple same StoreId in the record table but dfferent StatusID

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM records AS A
WHERE A.StatusID = 1 
AND NOT EXISTS (select B.StoreID 
                from records AS B 
                where B.StoreID = A.StoreIDB 
                and B.StatusID = 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assumming non-null StatusID field (is always filled in):

```
SELECT * FROM records AS A
   LEFT JOIN records AS B 
    on B.StoreID = A.StoreID
     and B.StatusID = 2
WHERE A.StatusID = 1 AND B.StatusID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You're still seeing the result even if StatusID = 2 exists because you're using a `LEFT JOIN`, which as you'll remember returns the entire left set and all matching entries from the right set or a NULL where none exist.

Seems to me the easiest fix is to just use an `INNER JOIN`, since for the cases `LEFT JOIN` will return that `INNER JOIN` won't, StatusID will equal neither 1 nor 2.

Thus:

```
select * from records a
inner join records b
on b.storeid = a.storeid
where a.statusid = 1
and b.statusid <> 2
```